# Why MS VS 2022 produces runtime error on std::future<T>::get()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20

I'm trying to figure out how `std::promise` and `std::future` can be used to get result from `std::jthread` in C++20. I'm using Visual Studio 2022. In a loop I'm trying to calculate if a given number is prime or not. The following program generates runtime error (`abort()` is called on 2nd iteration):

```
void IsPrime(uint64_t check, std::promise<bool> is_prime)
{
    if (check == 2)
        is_prime.set_value(true);
    if (check < 2 ||
        (check % 2 == 0) ||
        (check % 5 == 0))
        is_prime.set_value(false);

    for (uint64_t chase = 3; chase <= sqrt(check); chase += 2)
        if (check % chase == 0)
            is_prime.set_value(false);

    is_prime.set_value(true);
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 3; i < 100; i += 2)
    {
        std::promise<bool> prime_promise;
        std::future<bool> is_prime = prime_promise.get_future();
        std::jthread prime_thread =
            std::jthread(IsPrime, i, std::move(prime_promise));

        if (is_prime.get())
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It prints out 3 in the console after 1st iteration, and then `abort()` is called on the `is_prime.get()` statement on the 2nd iteration.

I was wondering what's is wrong here and why it doesn't fail in the 1st iteration but fails in the 2nd?

Comment: You apply `set_value` more than once - that's a bug.

Comment: @ALX23z, this is the correct answer. can you please post this answer so that i can chose it as best answer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `promise::set_value` must be applied once at most. You must to fulfil the promise by calling `set_value(_at_thread_exit)` or break the promise by either calling `set_exception(_at_thread_exit)` or destroying the promise. But regardless, such an action can only be performed once.

Think of this conceptually, one first calls `set_value(false)` then `set_value(true)`. What should its future return on `get`? False because it was called the earliest? Or true as it was assigned later? The `future/promise` were designed to return a single value and only once so calling `set_value` more than once is a bug in operating it.

To fix the issue you can call `return` after triggering `set_value`.

Note: the function `IsPrime` sets the promise to false for `check = 5` which is not ideal.

Note 2: you call `sqrt(check)` for every iteration which is not efficient. Also, it might not calculate the root perfectly and the code might exit before inspecting `sqrt(check)` when `check` is a perfect square. In fact, it will definitely fail when `check` is too large to be perfectly stored in a `double` resulting in inaccurate computation of `sqrt(check)`.